# make some 'li' in ul visible and hiding others

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Check my [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/63V3fwZhj7A9b5ntZQs1?p=preview), as you can see in plunker:

1. Menus are overflowing.
2. 'moveLeft' and 'moveRight' button will shift menus by -/+ 1.
3. If you reach to first and last menu, corresponding 'moveLeft' and 'moveRight ' will be disabled.

Earlier for `menucontainer` class  I was using `overflow:hidden` so menus were not oveflowing, but `overflow:hidden` was getting applied to child level menus also, they were cutting.
So finally I decided to remove `overflow:hidden` from `menucontainer` class.

So i thought of counting menus and making visible only required 3 menus and hiding all other. Things I am trying to achieve :

Let's assume currently 3 menus which are in middle are `444` `555` `666`

1. At a time 3 menus will be visible, all others will be hidden.
2. clicking 'moveRight' will shift menus by +1, i.e. `555` `666` `777` will be visible and rest all will be hidden.
3. clicking on 'moveLeft' will shift menus by -1, i.e. `333` `444` `555` will be visible and rest all will be hidden.

Is this achievable with javascript? I am new to js any assitacne will be highly appreciate.

Note: My web page is very complex, plunker is just showing problem in simplest way.
Please dont suggest to give overflow:hidden

**HTML Code**

```
<div>
  <input ng-click="myStyle={'margin-left': moveLeft()}" ng-show="menuItems > 3" ng-disabled="leftdisabled" class="left leftbtnposition" type="button" value="Move Left" />
  <div class="menucontainer left">
    <ul ng-style="myStyle">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items"> <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <input ng-click="myStyle={'margin-left': moveRight()}" ng-show="menuItems > 3" ng-disabled="rightdisabled" class="left rightbtnposition" type="button" value="Move Right" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menucontainer
 {
   width:300px;
   margin-left:200px;
/*   overflow:hidden;*/ not using this property now
 }
 .menucontainerhidden
 {
   width:300px;
   margin-left:200px;

 }
 .leftbtnposition
  {
   position:absolute;
   left:138px;
 }
 .rightbtnposition
  {
   position:absolute;
   left:510px;
 }
```

Comment: if you're on the first list item do you still want a minimum of 3 items visible? or is it more like the item to the left and to the right of the currently selected item if available?

Comment: yes minimum 3 menus will be visible anytime.
currently, if i am at first item 3 menus will be visible and 'moveleft' is disabled.

Comment: the key issue is to make only 3 menus visible and hiding other, and when user click on'moveLeft' and 'moveLeft' menus will shift along with -/+ 1. Let's assume visible menus are `444 555 666` so if i click on `moveRight` visible menus will be `555 666 777`. on clicking `moveLeft` it will be `333 444 555` .

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/ay7k1z6d/ I made this fiddle a while ago to answer someone else's question

Comment: @ctwheels  As mentioned in question can't use overflow:hidden .. in this fiddle you are showing 4 menus, and other are hidden because you have `overflow:hidden` in `#outer`. I commented this property http://jsfiddle.net/j23LbLko/ . now you can see all menus are visible. I am looking to make only 4 menus visible with same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can think to do this with your current set up is to apply a class to the items that you want to be hidden based off what is currently in the selected 3 items.

I added a `$scope.leftMost` variable to monitor the index in `$scope.items` is on the left of the visible area.

Then added a boolean to each `$scope.items` element called `isVisible`.

In the html file we add an `ng-class` that toggles a class based on this boolean `ng-class="{ hidden: !item.isVisible}"`

Then based off the `moveLeft` and `moveRight` methods you have already defined we use the `$scope.leftMost` variable to toggle the `isVisible` boolean as needed.

A little CSS magic for the `.hidden` class thrown in as well.

```
.menucontainer .hidden{
   opacity:0;
   visibility:hidden;
 }
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/NWFsn04ZVN0GGFQfEyC9?p=preview)

---

**ADDITIONAL**

Further to OP's comment, you can parse your returned data as it comes back into your service. For example:

```
.factory('MenuItems', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};

    var addVisible = function(menuItems){
        for(var x = 0; x < menuItems.videos.length; x++){
            var menuItem = menuItems[x];
            if(x < 3){
                menuItem.isVisible = true;
            }else{
                menuItem.isVisible = false;
            }
        }
        return menuItems;
    }

    factory.get = function () {
        var path = '/menuItemUrl/';
        return $http.get(path).then(function (resp) {
            if(resp.data.length){
                return addVisible(resp.data[0]);
            }
        });
    };
    return factory;
}])
```

Comment: need assistance, in plnkr i just shown json data, but in my application it's coming from service, so how do i add that isVisible property?

Comment: @ankit see **ADDITIONAL** section of answer

Answer (score 1):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/j23LbLko/2/)?

I modified the fiddle you posted in your comment(http://jsfiddle.net/j23LbLko/)

You can change the animation to whatever delay you want, it is currently set to 0.

**JS**

```
var myMargin = 112;
var numberOfVisibleItems = 3;
var numberOfItems = $('#menulist').children('li').length;

$('.left').click(function () {
    if (parseInt($('#menulist').css('margin-left'), 10) >= -(myMargin * (numberOfItems - (numberOfVisibleItems + (numberOfVisibleItems - 2))))) {
        $('#menulist').animate({
            'marginLeft': "-=" + myMargin + "px" //moves left
        }, 0, function () {
            hideItems();
        });
    }
});
$('.right').click(function () {
    if (parseInt($('#menulist').css('margin-left'), 10) >= 0) {
        $('#menulist').css('margin-left', '0px!important');
    } else {
        $('#menulist').animate({
            'marginLeft': "+=" + myMargin + "px" //moves right
        }, 0, function () {
            hideItems();
        });
    }
});

hideItems();

function hideItems() {
    var currentMarginLeft = parseInt($('#menulist').css("margin-left"), 10);
    var index = Math.abs(currentMarginLeft / myMargin);
    $('#menulist').children('li').css("visibility", "hidden");
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfVisibleItems; i++) {
        $('#menulist').children('li').eq(index + i).css("visibility", "visible");
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** (below)

---

Now just to let you know, both answers provided at the current time (my own and that of haxxxton) both have elements that are *simply hidden from view*. This means that when the items move left and right on the screen, your entire webpage's scrolling changes (left to right). This is because the *elements still exist and are simply hidden from sight*. Your **best** option would be to use the jsfiddle I included in my earlier comment ([this](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/ay7k1z6d/) one) and change the following values:

- In the **CSS**: `#outer { width:448px; }` **to** `#outer { width:336px; }`
- In the **JS** (in the left click event): `if (parseInt($('#menulist').css('margin-left'), 10) >= -784)` **to** `if (parseInt($('#menulist').css('margin-left'), 10) >= -896)`

**JS**

```
$('.left').click(function () {
    if (parseInt($('#menulist').css('margin-left'), 10) >= -784) {
        $('#menulist').animate({
            'marginLeft': "-=112px" //moves left
        });
    }
});
$('.right').click(function () {
    if (parseInt($('#menulist').css('margin-left'), 10) >= 0) {
        $('#menulist').css('margin-left', '0px!important');
    } else {
        $('#menulist').animate({
            'marginLeft': "+=112px" //moves right
        });
    }
});
```